# Uniform subspace of functions in $C^\infty_{\rm per}$ that vanish

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, vector-spaces, uniform-distribution

Let $X = C_{\rm per}^\infty([0, 1])$ denote the space of infinitely continuously differentiable, periodic functions $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e.,
$$
f(0) = f(1) = 0.
$$
Let $P = \{z_1, \dots, z_n\} \subset [0, 1]$ and define
$$
V(P) = \{u \in X : u |_P = 0\} = \bigcap_{z \in P} \{u \in X : u(z) = 0\}. 
$$
This is the set of functions in $X$ that vanish on $P$.

It seems that $V(P)$ is a subspace of codimension $n$ within $X$. What can be said about the structure of $V(P)$? Is it true that every subspace of $X$ with codimension $n$ can be written as $V(P_n)$ for some $|P_n| = n, P_n \subset[ 0, 1]$? I am particularly interested in the case where $P$ is comprised of $z_1, \dots, z_n$ which are independently, and uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: $X$ is by definition the equivlant classes of functions (where $f, g$ are identified if $f=g$ almost everywhere). So your $V(P)$ is just the whole $X$. (Or put it another way, it does not make sense to ask what is $f(a)$ for $f\in L^2 $).

Comment: I updated the question so that we are truly talking about functions, not equivalence classes.

Comment: The co-one-dimensional subspace $\{f\in X: \int_0^1 f(x)=0\}$ is not of the for $V(P)$.

Comment: I don't fully understand why your subspace has codimension 1.

Comment: Fix a $\phi$ so that $ \int_0^1 \phi (x) dx =1$, then every $f\in X$ can be written as $f = g + c\phi$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$ and $\int_0^1 g = 0$. @DrewBrady

Comment: What? How is that possible?